# Getting error ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found While installing Hive

Tags: java, apache, hive, log4j2, hadoop2

While I am installing hive on my Windows system, I am getting an error : ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Connecting to jdbc:hive2:// Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient Connection is already closed.Please suggest

Comment: *"Using default configuration..."* clearly means that Log4J recovers from the issue, it's just a warning *(yet another annoying thing to make logs less readable)*.

Comment: The real problem is in *"Unable to instantiate SessionHiveMetaStoreClient"* >> that message has to be propagated from HiveServer2; look into the server logs for details.